# If i call a function in fortran, without defining a variable, what happens?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

So i have a program, which has something like this in it:

```
integer :: mgvn, stot, gutot, iprint, iwrit, ifail, iprnt
...
call readbh(lubnd,nbset,nchan,mgvn,stot,gutot,nstat,nbound,rr,bform,iprnt,iwrit,ifail)
```

And then inside `readbh`:

```
      CALL GETSET(LUBND,NSET,KEYBC,BFORM,IFAIL)
      IF(IFAIL.NE.0) GO TO 99
      ...
 99   WRITE(IWRITE,98) NBSET,LUBND
      IFAIL = 1
      RETURN
```

Where all the other variables are defined, but `ifail` is not. If i add in `write(*,*) ifail` before the function call, i get the undefined variable error, but if i leave it out, it doesn't complain, and just runs away with the function, and always fails, with `IFAIL=1`.

Is this because it's just getting to the end of the arguments in the `readbh` function, reading in uninitialised memory - which is just random jibberish - and then casting those bits to an `int` - which is not going to be zero unless i'm very (un)lucky, and so nearly always making `ifail.ne.0` `true`?

Comment: Are you not defining ifail or are you leaving it off of the calling arg list? accessing an undefined variable is just that undefined. It might be zero or it might be whatever garbage happens to be in that memory location. If you access args in the subroutine that were not even supplied you will likely get a seg fault.

Comment: There is a reason for the `-Wuninitialized` flag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll choose to interpret what you call *undefined variable* as *uninitialised variable*.  Generally speaking Fortran, and many other compiled programming languages, will quite happily carry on computing with uninitialised variables.  It/they are programming languages for grown-ups, it's on our own head if you program this sort of behaviour.  It is not syntactically incorrect to write a Fortran program which uses uninitialised variables so a compiler is not bound by the language standard to raise a warning or error.

Fortran does, though, have the facility for you to program functions and subroutines to ensure that output arguments are given values.  If you use the `intent(out)` attribute on arguments which ought to have values assigned to them inside a procedure, then the compiler will check that an assignment is made and raise an error if one is not.

Most compilers have an option to implement run-time checking for use of uninitialised variables.  Intel Fortran, for example, has the flag `-check:uninit`. Without this check, yes, your program will interpret whatever pattern of bits it finds in the region of memory labelled `ifail` as an integer and carry on.

You write that your function always fails with `ifail == 1`.  From what you've shown us `ifail` is, just prior to the `return` at (presumably) the end of the call to `readbh`, unconditionally set to `1`.

From what you've revealed of your code it looks to me as if `ifail` is intended as an error return code from `getset` so it's not necessarily wrong that it is uninitialised on entry to that subroutine.  But it is a little puzzling that `readbh` then sets it to `1` before returning.

Comment: `IFAIL` is a variable that's passed as the last variable to many routines all over this code, and all over the place it just checks what it's value is, and in some of them just ends the program. In the example, there is a clause in `getset` which checks if `IFAIL` is `0`, and if it isn't, it will then set it to one and return nothing.

Comment: `ifort` also has a flag that will automatically initialize all uninitialized (numerical) variables to 0 (I think it's `-zero`).  I'm not suggesting it's good practice to let the compiler initialize the variables, but it's available if you inherit crappy code.